# Continuity of a function and its restriction

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,T)$ be a topological space and $A$ subset in $X$, and
$f:X\to (Y,t)$ a function.

If $A$ is open and $g:A\to Y$ is continuous (where $g$ is the restriction of $f$ on $A$) , then so is $f$.
Can someone prove it for me?

Comment: You could edit your question to state it correctly. What did you try, did you apply the definitions of continuity, and of subspace topology? Did you try to clarify to yourself what the question is asking?

Comment: Sure, and the stack-exchange community is very happy to help, but that part works a lot better if you give it a go first yourself, that's why @Mirko is asking.

Comment: As indicated in a now deleted comment, the statement is incorrect. You need to assume continuity on $X$ and prove continuity of the restriction on $A$, not the other way around. Also $g$ being a restriction of $f$ should in general go into $Y$, not into $X$. You did not specify, but $A\subseteq X$. Welcome to MSE! Usually you need to show more details of you attempted, to show understanding of the question and help people come up with a useful answer that would help your case.

Comment: Theorem. Every function $f:X\to Y$ is continuous. Proof. Let $A$ be the empty set $\emptyset$. Then the restriction $g:A\to Y$ is continuous. By @sarafkh question, $f$ is also continuous. QED

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to typeset math on this site.

Comment: it is clear (but you should state it in the question), and not difficult to prove. Do you use definition of continuity in terms of preimages of open sets being open? Then you use intersection of two open sets is open, and union of arbitrary many open (preimages) is open.

Comment: Your last comment is terse and unclear to me. Please edit your question, listing clearly what you assume,what you want answered, and what you have attempted, all in one place (not in comments) and preferably using mathjax. From your comments it also looks like you are asking different questions: These should be posted separately,each clearly stated. I almost posted an answer to the version where $A_i$ cover $X$, but I will not post it,as you seem to change the question repeatedly. If $A\subset X$ and $A\neq X$ then there is no such thing as $Id:X\to A$. If $y\in X\setminus A$ what is $Id(y)$?

Comment: The proposition with just one set $A$ is wrong. If the $A_i$ cover $X$ then the proposition is correct.

Comment: can someone write  the set of 

 1. natural numbers
 2. rational
 3. irrational
 4. real
using union of intervals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the additional assumption, stated in the comments (by the OP and later deleted), that $X=\cup\{A_i:i\in I\}$ (for some index set $I$) where each $A_i$ is open and each restriction $f:A_i\to Y$ is continuous, then indeed $f:X\to Y$ is continuous$.

Take any open $U\subset Y$ we need to show that $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$. Each $A_i\cap U$ is open, and hence, by continuity of $f$, we have that $f^{-1}(A_i\cap U)$ is open. 
Finally $f^{-1}(U)=\cup\{f^{-1}(A_i\cap U):i\in I\}$ is open, as the union of open sets.

Regarding the question as originally stated:
Let $X$ be a topological space and $A$ subset in $X$, and $f:X\to Y$ a function. If $A$ is open and $g:A\to Y$ is continuous (where $g$ is the restriction of $f$ on $A$), then so is $f$. Can someone prove it for me?

The above statement cannot be proved as it is incorrect. If it were correct, then it would imply that all functions between all topological spaces are continuous. Indeed, let $A$ be the empty set $\emptyset$. Then the restriction $g:A\to Y$ is continuous. If the above statement were correct, Then $f$ would also be continuous.

For a specific example, let $X=[0,1]$, $A=[0,1)$ and $Y=\Bbb R$ (or $Y=[0,1]$, or $Y=\{0,1\}$, either way). Let $f(x)=0$ for $x\in A$, and $f(1)=1$. Then $f$ is not continuous (since $\lim\limits_{x\to1^-}f(x)=0\neq1=f(1)$), even if the restriction of $f$ to $A$ is constant (and hence continuous).

For an even better/intuitive understanding take the following point of view. 
Start with $X,Y,A$ and continuous $g:A\to Y$. Then extend $g$ on all of $X$, arbitrarily, to obtain some function $f:X\to Y$. There are (in general) zillions of ways to obtain such extensions, and very few of them (under some special/additional conditions) would be continuous. Most of the time such an extension would be discontinuous. (@HennoBrandsma was also alluding to this, in a comment to his answer, I would believe.)

Comment: You need to also remark that $f^{-1}[U \cap A_i]$ is open in $A_i$ by the assumption and the fact that $A_i$ is open too implies the set is open in $X$ as well. An essential point to make IMO.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma thank you making that point for me. I didn't have to make it since you would :)

Comment: @sarafkh What is "*it*" that might or might not be true?

Answer (score 0):

So the data is: $(X, \mathcal{T})$ is a space, $f: (X,\mathcal{T}) \to (Y,\mathcal{T}')$ is a function to another space, $A\subseteq X$. You assume further that $A$ is open and $g=f \restriction A$ is continuous, and you want to show $f$ is continuous? This is clearly false: take as a trivial example $X=\{0,1\}$ with the Sierpinski topology, $Y=\{0,1\}$ in the discrete topology, $f=\text{id}$, which is not continuous even though $f\restriction A$ is continuous and open for $A=\{0\}$.

So you probably mean something else?

Comment: read the comments and the several edits to the problem, to get a clarification that it is not clear at all what is meant

Comment: @sarafkh You should ask clearer questions. It should be intuitively clear that assiming something on the restricted map does not give much info on the original unless maybe $A$ is somehow "big" in $X$, say (although in this trivial example $A$ is also dense)

Comment: @sarafkh What exactly is "*that*"

Comment: though the OP erased their comments, so too late now ...